# iOS - Parse.com sorting by relational object property

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is there a way to sort a query by a relational object's property in Parse? It doesn't throw me an error when I try sorting by username, but it also doesn't sort the objects correctly.

```
// Query for all friends the current user is following
var relationshipQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Relationship")
relationshipQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: currentUser)

// Include the user
relationshipQuery.includeKey("followed")

// Order by username
relationshipQuery.orderByDescending("username")
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code isn't trying to order by the username in the relational object. But it=s looking for a username column in the Relationship class and ordering by that. I assume if it doesn't find anything it just doesn't sort your results

Comment: Is there anyway to make it order by username? Or do I need to do a PFUser query?

Comment: I don't believe you can order on a member varaible of a relation object no, sorry.

Comment: Did you find a way to accomplish this?